# How to iterate chosen operation through different csv files and output the result to new csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I'm attempting to use the pandas and os to take CSV files from a chosen directory and delete specified rows iteratively, as they are produced in a form that I don't like. Following the iteration, I'd like the CSVs to be output with the same name+a suffix to indicate that the iteration has been performed.

I am coming back to Python after a long hiatus, but here is what I have so far:

```
DIR = 'Dummy_Folder/'

JV_suffix = "Current-Voltage Data.csv"
# For each file name in the chosen directory (DIR)
for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
    # If file name ends with chosen suffix perform...
    if filename.endswith(JV_suffix):
        # Read the original csv file InputName
        data = pd.read_csv(filename,header=None)
        # Defining the rows that we want to delete from the file
        trim = [0,1,2,len(data)-1,len(data)-2,len(data)-3]
        # Deleting these rows and defining new csv
        trim_data = data.drop(trim,axis=0) 
        # Making data frame with trimmed csv
        df = pd.DataFrame(trim_data)
        # Outputting df to CSV with suffix of '_number'
        df.to_csv('DIR/filename_{}'.format(filename),index=False)
    else:
        continue
```

When I run this on dummy data it throws error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Dummy_Current-Voltage Data.csv'`

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Try replacing `data = pd.read_csv(filename,header=None)` by `data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DIR, filename),header=None)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably an error concerning the relative path of your files.

I presume your folder `Dummy/` is on the python projects path.
If the folder is found correctly, the correct relative path for any file inside of the folder should be `Dummy/filename`.

You can use `os.path.join(foldername,filename)` to join the folder name and filename.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you qouify and Sam for the suggestion, this solved the problem, along with changing the output CSV line to `df.to_csv('trimmed_{}'.format(filename),index=False)`. I think the inclusion of DIR in the filename was causing problems. I attach the whole script below as a demonstration for others who have similar queries

```
import pandas as pd
import os, os.path

DIR = 'Dummy_Folder/'
# For each file name in the chosen directory (DIR)
for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
    # If file name ends with chosen suffix perform...
    if filename.endswith("Current-Voltage Data.csv"):
        # Read the original csv file
        data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(DIR, filename),header=None)
        # Defining the rows that we want to delete from the file
        trim = [0,1,2,len(data)-1,len(data)-2,len(data)-3]
        # Deleting these rows and defining new csv
        trim_data = data.drop(trim,axis=0) 
        # Making data frame with trimmed csv
        df = pd.DataFrame(trim_data)
        df.to_csv('trimmed_{}'.format(filename),index=False)
    else:
        continue
```